# How can I get a good ML code with good documentation to compare my model with

Tags: github, model, performance-testing, image-segmentation, few-shot-learning

I finish training my model, and I get a good result. My problem is medical image segmentation using 3D images and few-shot learning. Now I want to compare my result with state-of-the-art methods for research purposes. I need help finding a clean code with good documentation because I want to change their dataset with a different one. How do others compare their work? Are they spending a lot of time trying others' code while some codes are poorly written, missing files, not working, no response on the issue section, poor support, not updated, etc.

Are there any recommendations?